# Import raw files from typescript with webpack using the `import` statement

Tags: typescript, webpack

I need to import raw data from typescript using webpack.
Here is my setup:

```
$ tree
.
+-- file.txt
+-- main.ts
+-- package.json
+-- tsconfig.json
+-- webpack.config.js
```

**file.txt**

```
file-content
```

**main.js**

```
import file from './file.txt';

console.log(file);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "ts-loader": "^3.1.1",
    "typescript": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": "app"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  entry: './main.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.txt$/, use: 'raw-loader' },
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

when I run weback, it says it can't find the module:

```
ERROR in ./main.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /tmp/test/main.ts(1,18)
      TS2307: Cannot find module './file.txt'.
```

My question is: How can I import txt data into a typescript file? This is useful when writing an angular component, for example, and importing an html template to assign it to the template property of that component.

Comment: @Fenton: Does not work. And where would the content of the file be? I need it in a variable to use it.

Comment: @Kacper, the question you are referring to is not using webpack but systemjs. Besides, the solution looks like an ugly workaround.

Comment: There is a problem in Typescript modules resolution, so it doesn't matter if you are using systemjs or webpack. Typescript module resolver is looking for .ts/.tsx/.js/.jsx files, so you need to declare module before importing it.

Comment: I believe there is more to it. By creating an appropriate [declaration.d.ts](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#shorthand-ambient-modules) there error goes away but it does not work. It prints "undefined". Looking at the generated bundle, the module is messed up somehow. So either webpack or the raw-loader is not getting along with it. I am suprised that this does not work. It used to with js/babel and I would expect people to need that feature.

Comment: You are missing resolve section in you webpack configuration.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/#importing-other-assets in webpack documentation. So you probably need to do the same but for *.txt extension.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So I finally got it to work. I have added module declaration in .d.ts file:

```
declare module '*.txt' {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

And only then I imported .txt file like this:

```
const someTextContent = require('./some.txt');
```

You can find more about this [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/#importing-other-assets).

EDIT:

If you want to use `import` keyword just use it as following:

```
import * as someTextContent from './some.txt';
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen that solution in the discussion of the question you pointed too, but I'd rather keep using import. Using require looks like a workaround to me.

Comment: Edited answer. You can use import easily, but you still have to include module declaration for Typescript in *.d.ts files.

Comment: In your `declare module ...` statement, you can also use `const content: string`, so the `someTextContent` will be a string.

Comment: content type should be string `const content: string`

Comment: The `import` syntax didn't work for me. Changing to `require` avoids errors on compile, but doesn't copy the included file to the built directory (or pack it). What am I missing? Are there restrictions on what the `.d.ts` file can be named or where it must live?

Answer (score 9):

I added a global definition file `global.d.ts` in src root and added:

```
declare module "*.txt" {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

I didn't need any extra `tsconfig.json`, and I just had the standard webpack rule for `raw-loader`:

```
rules: [
   {
      test: /\.txt$/i,
      loader: 'raw-loader',
   },
```

Then I could import a plain text file called `./source.js.txt` into ts variable like this:

```
import txt from './source.js.txt'
```

It seemed more to do with making TS happy than webpack. The key seems to be the module definition. Either global or per file if needed.

Comment: It's "Asset Modules" since Webpack v5: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules

Answer (score 2):

> Prior to webpack v5 it was common to use `raw-loader` to import file contents as a string.

now you can use `type: 'asset/source'` to import the raw text of a file.

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ...
      {
        resourceQuery: /raw/,
        type: 'asset/source',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

if you use typescript, create a declaration file in your project folder (choose any name):

```
//declarations.d.ts

declare module '*?raw' {
  const content: string
  export default content
}
```

```
- import text from 'file.txt';
+ import text from 'file.txt?raw';
```

this way, no matter what the file extension is, you can import it as raw text just by adding `?raw` to the import address

source: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/

Comment: But what about TS files that are already being transpiled by another loader/rule? How do I `?raw` load its content before transpilation?

Comment: @Martin if you'd like to exclude raw assets from being processed by other loaders, use a negative condition: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#:~:text=and%20if%20you%27d%20like%20to%20exclude%20raw%20assets%20from%20being%20processed%20by%20other%20loaders%2C%20use%20a%20negative%20condition%3A