# Can't find module TS2307 in React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import text from "./compiler/test/index.txt";
import "./App.css";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  // const compiler = new Compiler("../test/index.jack");
  // compiler.save();
  console.log("text: ", text);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I'm using react-app-rewired to override webpack configuration, without ejecting. 
This component reads a .txt file and logs its content, but there is an error, `Cannot find module './compiler/test/index.txt'. TS2307` in the third line of import.

Comment: This is probably just because the type `.txt` is not defined in any typescript definition. Does the import work? If so, you probably just need to define the type somewhere. For example in a `global.d.ts` in the root folder. You can check the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122504/import-raw-files-from-typescript-with-webpack-using-the-import-statement

Comment: Thank you @Daniel. create-react-app with typescript project has a file called react-app-env.d.ts by default, that is where new types declared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As my comment seemed to resolve the issue, here as an official answer:

You probably just need to declare the type `.txt` somewhere in your typescript definitions. For create-react-app, this would be in `react-app-env.d.ts`. E.g.:

```js
declare module '*.txt' {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```