# "Cannot find module" when using raw-loader and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, webpack, raw-loader

I'm trying to include some WebGL vertex and fragment shaders by `import`ing them as strings.

I have a project structure like this:

```
myproj/
  src/
    shad/
      foo.frg
      foo.vtx
    shad.d.ts
    Foo.ts
  dist/
    ...
  built/
    ...
  tsconfig.json
  package.json
  webpack.config.js
```

**shad.d.ts**

```
declare module '*.vtx' {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}

declare module '*.frg' {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
```

**Foo.ts**

```
import stuff from 'shad/foo.frg'

console.log(stuff)
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "include": [
        "src/**/*", 
        "src/shad/**/*.vtx", 
        "src/shad/**/*.frg",
    ], 
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2018",
        "module": "es2015",
        "declaration": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "built",
        "composite": true,
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    test: './src/Foo.ts',
  },
  mode:    'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test:    /\.tsx?$/,
        use:     'ts-loader',
        exclude: [
          /node_modules/,
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(vtx|frg)$/i,
        use:  'raw-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.vtx', '.frg' ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path:      path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

**When I `npx webpack`, I get:**

```
ERROR in ./src/Foo.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'shad/foo.frg' in '/Users/tbabb/test/tmp/tsproj/src'
 @ ./src/Foo.ts 1:0-33 4:16-21
```

Also, the `src/shad/` folder and its contents are absent from the `built/` directory.

I've been around and around in all the docs for TypeScript and Webpack, as well as plenty of other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122504/import-raw-files-from-typescript-with-webpack-using-the-import-statement) here. From most of what I've read, the existence and contents of `shad.d.ts` should be enough to solve this problem, but it doesn't— and I don't even know how to figure out why.

What's going on? What do I have to do to import a raw file in Webpack with TypeScript? (Or at the very least, what can I do to figure out why this isn't being found?)

Answer (score 7):

In my case with Next.js (also Typescript), I solved it by just installing raw-loader. Really.

```
npm install raw-loader
```

It turned out that raw-loader didn't come with my Next.js project. I am a newbie so I **assumed** it came with my project.

So for anyone else encountering the same problem, check your package.json file to see if raw-loader is there at all before trying out other solutions.

[image: raw-loader dependency]

Answer (score 0):

In this particular repro case, I accidentally omitted the "./" from the import in `Foo.ts`. It should read:

```
import stuff from './shad/foo.frg'
```

The actual problem that prompted this question I have narrowed down to [an apparent bug](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader/issues/95) with project references in `raw-loader`.

Answer (score -1):

Rename the file **shad.d.ts** to **global.d.ts** and move to the root of your source directory (right next to **index.ts**). This got the typescript compiler to pick it up for me.